# Using PHP's exec() function that runs a java program that runs a python program - but it breaks when it gets to the python call

Tags: java, python, php, exec

I am using PHP's exec function to run a java program:

```
exec("java evalQuery tempQuery.xml none all", $o, $r);
```

`evalQuery` is a java program that makes several Runtime exec calls to other Java programs and Python programs to evaluate a query. While there is no problem with the exec calls to the other Java programs, it breaks when there is an exec call to a Python program. However, `evalQuery` runs fine when run from the command line. I have also tried `shell_exec()` and other PHP functions for program execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: "it breaks" will not get us far.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was easier than I thought although it took some time. The call to Python from the Java program has to include the full path to python interpreter.